# Custom Pattern Pencil Sketch Drawing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, core-graphics

Using Core Graphics, I want the painting app functionality and here the user can have the custom image pattern drawing functionality.I followed the proceeding snippet :

```
enter code here
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
  [T_BImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(rotX-(T_BImage.size.width)/2, rotY-(T_BImage.size.height)/2) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
```

drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[image: .]
Here , is the output.
But ,when the user continuously drags fast on the screen , then the image is not sequentially drawn whereas the same code works fine with slow drag

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the image is drawn with the direct proportion of user's drawing speed. This was achieved by calculating the smallest set of points between touches_began and touches_moved delegate methods.i.e. All the set of possible points from minimum (starting) CGPoint to Maximum(Inbetween moving or end)point was manually calibrated and those points are passed through the image drawing function concurrently with separate thread.

Thanks to Brad-Larson for his remarkable .
[response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615492/cant-draw-fast-enough-to-keep-up-with-touchesmoved)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is as the drag speeds up, there will be continuous calls to the same method which might be rendering this slow. If you are planning to paint the pattern image, I suggest you try and look into the apple sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328)

You will have to replace the pattern image in the above sample project with your custom pattern image. See how it goes. One point to be noted is that the pattern image has to be square shaped(same width and height)

Comment: Thanks Naresh. I tried it but it takes only the lower left corner pixel of my image . Also, I have taken square dimensioned image only.

Comment: What is the size of your pattern image?

Comment: I just double checked it. Seems I was wrong. The image needs to be a power of 2 (16,32,64 etc.) to be able to paint that way. Try to put it with such dimensions and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: FYI,it just draws the shades of RGB but doesn't considers any pattern.Please scrutinise it . Thanks for reconsideration.

Comment: The size of the image is 32x32